# Google api validate purchasetokens verify receipt

Tags: validation, google-api, in-app-purchase, token, androidpublisher

I have a question about purchase token validation with the google api. So far I send the purchasetoken from the client to my backend and validate it together with the product sku, but how can I validate the amount of the purchased product?

[image]

After allowing multiple purchases for the same product, how can I validate the amount together with the purchasetoken and product sku? This is the code that validates only purchasetoken and product sku that I use:

> ```
> purchases = service.purchases()
> subscriptions = purchases.subscriptions()
> subscriptions_get = subscriptions.get(
>     packageName=self.bundle_id, subscriptionId=product_sku, token=purchase_token
> )
> result = subscriptions_get.execute(http=self.http)
> return result
> ```